# There exists a unique $2\times2$ real symmetric matrix $A$ with $\mathrm{tr}\,A=a$ and $\det A=b$ iff $a^2 = 4b$

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let   $a$ and $b$ be real numbers.
Show that there is a unique $2 \times 2$ real symmetric matrix $A$ with $\operatorname{trace} (A)= a $ and $\det (A)=b $ iff $a^2 = 4b$.

I know that the eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are all real, using that I am getting $a^2\geq 4b$.

But how to get the answer.

Comment: "With trace ..." **what**?

Comment: It would be trace A= a.sorry

Answer (score 3):

Let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ the two real eigenvalues of $A$. Then

$$\det(A)=\lambda_1\lambda_2=b\quad \text{and}\quad \operatorname{Tr}(A)=\lambda_1+\lambda_2=a$$
so $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the solutions of $x^2-ax+b=0$.

Moreover, $A$ is unique iff $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ iff the discriminant of the quadratic equation $\Delta=a^2-4b=0$.

Answer (score 3):

For a $\;2\times 2\;$ matrix $\;A\;$ , we get that its characteristic polynomial is $\;t^2-\left(\text{Tr.}\,A\right)\,t+\det A\;$ , so we put

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}\cfrac a2&0\\0&\cfrac a2\end{pmatrix}$$

Any other **symmetric** $\;2\times2\;$ matrix fulfilling the above will have to be

$$\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\y&z\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\text{and also}\;\;\begin{cases}&I\;\;&x+z=a\\{}\\&II\;\;&xz-y^2=b\end{cases}$$

Solving this system we get:

$$I:\;z=a-x\stackrel{II}\implies ax-x^2-y^2=b\iff-\left(x-\frac a2\right)^2-y^2=b-\frac{a^2}4$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry I did not get it

Comment: In the last line above the left side is $\,\le0$. You already got, by discriminant of the quadratic charac. polynomial, that $\;a^2\ge 4b\;$ . 

If $\;a^2>4b\iff b-\frac{a^2}4<0\;$ , last line is
$$\left(x-\frac a2\right)^2+y^2=\frac{a^2}4-b>0\implies\;\text{with any pair}\;(x,y)\;\text{on this circle we form a}\;\;2\times2$$symmetric matrix whose trace is $\;a\;$ and its determinant is $\;b\;$ . Thus, it **must** be $\;a^2=4b\;$ so that the equation $\;\left(x-\frac a2\right)^2+y^2=\frac{a^2}4-b=0\;$ is one unique point: $\;x=\frac a2\,,\,y=0\;$ , and our matrix is unique.